# How do I set locale when building an Ubuntu Docker image with Packer?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, localization, packer

I'm using [Packer](https://www.packer.io/) to build a Docker image based on Ubuntu 14.04, i.e., in my Packer template I have:

```
"builders": [{
    "type": "docker",
    "image": "ubuntu",
    "commit": true
}],
```

and I build it using:

```
$ packer build my.json
```

What do I need to put in the template to get a specific locale (say `en_GB`) to be set when I subsequently run the following?

```
$ sudo docker run %IMAGE_ID% locale
```

### Additional info

As it stands, I get:

```
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
...
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

which causes a few problems for things I want to do next, like installing certain Python packages.

I've tried adding:

```
{
    "type": "shell",
    "inline": [
        "locale-gen en_GB.UTF-8",
        "update-locale LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8"
    ]
}
```

but while that does set up the locale config it doesn't affect the env used by docker run. Even if I add extra export lines like:

```
{
    "type": "shell",
    "inline": [
    ...
        "export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8"
    ]
}
```

they have no effect, presumably because when using `docker run`, it's not a child process of the command `packer build` uses when running these commands initially.

As a workaround I can pass env vars to `docker run`, but don't want to have to do that each time, e.g.:

```
sudo docker run -e LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 -e LANGUAGE=en_GB.UTF-8 -e LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8 %IMAGE_ID% locale
```

Comment: I couldn't tag this 'packer' or 'packer.io' as they're new tags and I've not got the reputation.

Comment: I tried a couple things (adding variables to `/etc/environment` and `/root/.profile`) but couldn't find a decent workaround. Packer does at least call this out at http://www.packer.io/docs/builders/docker.html#toc_8 and they do realize that certain Dockerfile metadata (in this case `ENV`) isn't available to set.

Comment: FYI, [tag:packer] has been [added](http://serverfault.com/tags/packer/info) via a question I asked on [Meta Server Fault](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/7856/add-packer-tag) for the moderators (I don't have sufficient rep to add it directly either).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but according to the documentation, you should be able to do this using the `docker-import` post-processor: https://www.packer.io/docs/post-processors/docker-import.html

Example:

```
{
  "type": "docker-import",
  "repository": "local/ubuntu",
  "tag": "latest",
  "changes": [
    "ENV LC_ALL en_GB.UTF-8"
  ]
}
```